# Regex Nifi pass list of words in the table name pattern property

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

​How can I pass a list of table names to "CaptureChangeMySQL processor" that it should capture if any change happen to any table in that list? I tried few regex variations to accept a list of table names( e.g. Product and Order here), but no luck:

(?:^|(?<= ))(Product|Order)(?:(?= )|$)

(?:[\s]|^)(Product|Order)(?=[\s]|$)

^.*.(?Product$|Order$)[^.]+$

.*\b(Product|Order)\b.*

(Product|Order)

Answer (score 0):

I think the table names regex you are looking for is

```
Product|Order
```

NiFi does not require or use a matching group in this style of filter.

Comment: Thanks, James. I tried but it stopped capturing any table. I'm putting it in the value field of "CaptureChangeMySQL" for the property "Table Name Pattern". Aim : Filter only few tables on which the processors should work. Am I missing anything?